# Nagios http url check fails with "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to configure a `http_check` using the -u parameter to check a specific URL, but while this works fine from the command line, the nagios check only returns `Temporary failure in name resolution`

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H 176.67.169.157 -u http://dolicapax.org/
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 10960 bytes in 0.360 second response time |time=0.359959s;;;0.000000 size=10960B;;;0
```

Here's the command and service definitions

```
# 'check_http_url' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http_url
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -I '$HOSTADDRESS' -u '$ARG1$'
}


define service {
        host_name               frank.olsenit.no
        service_description     HTTP-wiki
        check_command           check_http_url!http://dolicapax.org/
        ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Found it .. simple typo - needs another $ in $HOSTADDRESS$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just this

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H 176.67.169.157 -u /
```

If you need to put a host in use

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H dolicapax.org -I 176.67.169.157 -u /
```

Check to make sure you can resolve on the host also

```
nslookup dolicapax.org
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider that way of doing it. Will it work with virtual hosts?

Comment: yes it will. That's the same setup i use to check vhosts

Comment: Lovely, I noticed this way http_check does a HTTP/1.1 request instead of HTTP/1.0. Much better this way, thanks again.

Comment: right cause in 1.1 the host header is needed.. 1.0 it isn't

Comment: Adding host (-H) and ip (-I) worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the `check_command` in your commands.cfg with:

```
service {
        host_name               frank.olsenit.no
        service_description     HTTP-wiki
        check_command           check_http_url!176.67.169.157!http://dolicapax.org/
}
```

Check your files:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
```

Restart nagios and check your nagios site.

Comment: I don't think this will work without changing the command definition, will it? Anyway, I found the typo in my configuration, it just needed an extra dollar sign in $HOSTADDRESS$